# Using Hibernates SQLQuery to search documents between Date ranges

Tags: java, sql, date, timezone, timestamp

I have a database containing a list of clips. Each clip has a startTime and an endTime both timestamps with timezone. What I'm trying to do is get all the clips that fall inside a time range ( start - end ). I have two objects of type Date in my java program and I create an SQL Query from hibernate :

```
select * from clips where (start_time IN(?,?) or end_time IN(?,?)) and clips.mediaid=? order by clips.id ASC
```

I set the Date parameters using the setDate(int arg0, Date arg1) method of the SQLQuery but when I execute I only get results when the date range ( start - end ) has at least a difference of a whole day. It's as if the result sql query totally ignores the time difference and compares only the date ( year, month, day ).

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
(start_time >= ? and end_time <= ?)
```